# Java Validating Date entry

Tags: java, date, format, error-checking

I want to know is there a way to check the Java Date format to makes sure that a user doesn't enter a date like 56-13-2013 where the format is dd-MM-yyyy.
Currently when I enter a date with 13 months it will carry over to add one year and then will display  1 month.
E.g. 16-16-2013 will give me 16-04-2014.

Comment: You can also look into using a JDateChooser. Much cleaner and less user error prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setLenient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient-boolean-) to validate the input `Date` `String`

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
format.setLenient(false);
Date date = format.parse(myDateString);
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't have the <setLenient(false);>

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how you're currently parsing the value - I assume it's with `SimpleDateFormat`. Just call `setLenient(false)` and that should validate the input.

For example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        // Prints a value in 2014
        System.out.println(format.parse("16-16-2013"));
        format.setLenient(false);
        // Throws an exception
        System.out.println(format.parse("16-16-2013"));        
    }
}
```

If you're doing any significant amount of work, I'd also highly recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in classes.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

This can be controlled by using the appropriate `ResolverStyle` that offers three different approaches, strict, smart and lenient. The smart option is the default which can resolve the day-of-month as long as it is in the range of 1-31, and month as long as it is in the range of 1-12.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        demonstrateResolverStyles("56-13-2013");
        demonstrateResolverStyles("29-02-2013");
        demonstrateResolverStyles("32-02-2013");
        demonstrateResolverStyles("28-13-2013");
    }

    static void demonstrateResolverStyles(String input) {
        System.out.println("Input string: " + input);
        try {
            System.out.println("Parsed using ResolverStyle.LENIENT => " + LocalDate.parse(input,
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-u", Locale.ENGLISH).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT)));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            // Default is ResolverStyle.SMART
            System.out.println("Parsed using ResolverStyle.SMART => "
                    + LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-u", Locale.ENGLISH)));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Parsed using ResolverStyle.STRICT => " + LocalDate.parse(input,
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-u", Locale.ENGLISH).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Input string: 56-13-2013
Parsed using ResolverStyle.LENIENT => 2014-02-25
Text '56-13-2013' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 13
Text '56-13-2013' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 13

Input string: 29-02-2013
Parsed using ResolverStyle.LENIENT => 2013-03-01
Parsed using ResolverStyle.SMART => 2013-02-28
Text '29-02-2013' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'February 29' as '2013' is not a leap year

Input string: 32-02-2013
Parsed using ResolverStyle.LENIENT => 2013-03-04
Text '32-02-2013' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 32
Text '32-02-2013' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 32

Input string: 28-13-2013
Parsed using ResolverStyle.LENIENT => 2014-01-28
Text '28-13-2013' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 13
Text '28-13-2013' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 13
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/aR3sj2)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>